# update main table from two others with modification of data before updating

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have two tables that I need to update.  I have to go through every record on one table then do some modifications to the data then upload the modified 
data to another table!

The two tables have 3,000 records and 11,000 records.  Plus I also have to 
check some info from a third table with about 50 records!

```vb
Dim id
Dim fly_SQL
id="user1"
Dim rsc1_conn As ADODB.Connection

Set rsc1_conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
rsc1_conn.Provider = "SQLOLEDB"
rsc1_conn.ConnectionString = "SERVER=companyserver;UID=" & id & 
";Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=DATAbank" '
rsc1_conn.Open

Set rsc1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM main_database", 
dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
rsc1.movefirst
do until rsc1.EOF 

    fly_SQL = "Select * from alt_db where alt_db.number = main.net_number" 

    Set rsc2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(fly_SQL)

    do stuff 

    code = dlookup( "type_def", "third_rec" , alt_db.activity = activity)
```

The two tables both use *net_number* as a reference which on the main is primary key unique, but the *alt_db* has multiple entries.

So basically I have to loop through each *net_number* on the main,  look at the matching *net_number* on the *alt_db* then compare an *activity* field 
with a third table to see which field I update on the main! If it's a Project management expense I put it in the `main.PM_cost`. The *net_number* in *alt_db* might repeat for 10 other expenses that need to be funneled into their proper expense categories in the main DB! As an example:

Main table looks like

```
net_number
```

first record shows

```
main.netnumber = 123456 
main.cont_cost
main.PM_cost
main.mgmt_cost
```

alt_db table looks like

```
alt_db.net_number
alt_db.activity
alt_db.PM_cost
alt_db.const_cost
alt_db.mgmt_cost
```

third_rec looks like

```
third_rec.code
third_type
```

where data can be something like con1 ,  sabb ,

```
code     type
sauf     construction
con1     management
I130     project management
```

And needed rules:

- check `alt_db.activity`  with `third_rec.act`  and return  `activity` type
- If activity type is construction then I put the `alt_db.cost` into `main.const_cost`
- If activity type is *project_mgmt* then I put the `alt_db.cost` into `main.PM_cost`. The alt_db.activity could be con1 or SAF4  and the type is determined by the *third_rec* table.

Trying to figure out the best (most efficient way) to go about this.

Any suggestions?

The above code will surely be missing proper variable definitions and such but it's just for explaining my dilemma!

I could probably do it with `DLookup` but I don't think that would be very efficient!

Pete

Comment: You want someone to analyze your db and write working code? Not likely in this case. You need to write a procedure and when you have a SPECIFIC issue (error message, wrong result, nothing happens), post question. All this checking and updating indicates to me you do not have optimal data structure.

Comment: No I wanted suggestions on the best way to go about it!  What suggestion would be the most efficient. I'll write the code, but I want to start out in the right direction.I got an excellent suggestion on another board the said I should do it via a query and outlined how I could go about it. Once I knew which direction to take coding it is going well! The hardest part is done!

Comment: Best way was to build a query that produces a file filtered data from the Main and alt_db to group the activities by net_number . Then use a case to determine which fields to update from the third file and update the result.

Answer (score 0):

Best way was to build a query that produces a file filtered data from the Main and alt_db to group the activities by net_number . Then use a case to determine which fields from alt_db to update using the third file and update the result in the proper fields on the main db.